# group data by months of 6 years

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, pandas-groupby

i have a csv file containing 6 years of data starting from 01/01/2006 to 01/01/2011 and i need to group data by each month of the 6 years.
here's an overview of my csv file :

```
 timestamp,heure,lat,lon,impact,type
 2006-01-01 00:00:00,13:58:43,33.837,-9.205,10.3,1
 2006-01-02 00:00:00,00:07:28,34.5293,-10.2384,17.7,1
 2007-02-01 00:00:00,23:01:03,35.0617,-1.435,-17.1,2
 2007-02-02 00:00:00,01:14:29,36.5685,0.9043,36.8,1
 2008-01-01 00:00:00,05:03:51,34.1919,-12.5061,-48.9,1
 2008-01-02 00:00:00,05:03:51,34.1919,-12.5061,-48.9,1
 ....
 2011-12-31 00:00:00,05:03:51,34.1919,-12.5061,-48.9,1
```

and here's the output desired :

```
 month 01   10 (counts of the columns)
 month 02   20
 .....
 month 12   30
```

any ideas ??

Comment: So you expect 12 rows summarizing all Januarys, Februarys,... Decembers?

Comment: yes exactly, that's why i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the sample dataframe `df`

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])

tidx = pd.date_range('2006-01-01', '2011-01-01', name='Date')

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        heure=pd.to_timedelta(np.random.randint(24*60*60, size=len(tidx))),
        lat=np.random.rand(len(tidx)) * 10 + 30,
        lon=np.random.rand(len(tidx)) * 10 - 20,
        impact=np.random.rand(len(tidx)),
        type=np.random.randint(3, size=len(tidx))
    ), tidx)

df.head()

                     heure    impact        lat        lon  type
Date                                                            
2006-01-01 00:00:00.000037  0.312643  39.324254 -14.715073     1
2006-01-02 00:00:00.000019  0.121450  30.560726 -10.879014     0
2006-01-03 00:00:00.000060  0.080082  38.489212 -11.899611     1
2006-01-04 00:00:00.000021  0.270159  34.832683 -14.924849     0
2006-01-05 00:00:00.000066  0.112194  32.193704 -19.083123     0
```

Use `df.index.month` to group by

```
df.groupby(df.index.month).size()

Date
1     156
2     141
3     155
4     150
5     155
6     150
7     155
8     155
9     150
10    155
11    150
12    155
dtype: int64
```

You can do all the things you'd normally do with a group by... Here is an example using describe

```
df.groupby(df.index.strftime('%B')).impact.describe()

      count      mean       std       min       25%       50%       75%       max
Date                                                                             
1     156.0  0.529216  0.279498  0.003298  0.292654  0.538437  0.774256  0.998507
2     141.0  0.501540  0.295111  0.001063  0.243723  0.491919  0.727560  0.999231
3     155.0  0.516168  0.306878  0.001178  0.227668  0.556316  0.783676  0.997126
4     150.0  0.472035  0.263685  0.004031  0.246738  0.491169  0.665894  0.987965
5     155.0  0.523897  0.320709  0.003486  0.221323  0.538594  0.841909  0.994280
6     150.0  0.542496  0.297215  0.003550  0.273098  0.589802  0.807086  0.995538
7     155.0  0.513857  0.285404  0.000933  0.285383  0.519170  0.746735  0.999551
8     155.0  0.516404  0.284407  0.004662  0.288900  0.545429  0.739392  0.996601
9     150.0  0.490965  0.299312  0.011958  0.206851  0.487708  0.737785  0.993217
10    155.0  0.513743  0.304779  0.010712  0.199390  0.563746  0.796143  0.995488
11    150.0  0.465428  0.271936  0.006345  0.221753  0.470793  0.684867  0.995886
12    155.0  0.498415  0.301704  0.004538  0.215730  0.471139  0.757360  0.997268
```

Comment: @MarieAntoinette you are welcome... just remember to keep your head :-)  Sorry, I couldn't help myself.

Answer (score 1):

it would work:

```
df["month"]=df["timestamp"].dt.month
df.groupby(["month"].size()
```

Comment: yeah i tried it and it's working...thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I mostly use resample to do this.

Here are my samples:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
index = pd.date_range('2017/1/1', '2017/10/1')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((274, 1)), index)
df
          0
2017-01-01  1.0
2017-01-02  1.0
...         ...
2017-09-29  1.0
2017-09-30  1.0
2017-10-01  1.0

df.resample('M').count()  # use resample to agg data
2017-01-31  31
2017-02-28  28
2017-03-31  31
2017-04-30  30
2017-05-31  31
2017-06-30  30
2017-07-31  31
2017-08-31  31
2017-09-30  30
2017-10-31   1
```